# How to get the loop induction variables' name in LLVM?

Tags: llvm

I want to get the loop induction variables' name, is it right to get the name as following?

```
void analyze_loop(Loop* loop) {
    errs() << loop->getCanonicalInductionVariable()->getName() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that looks correct - assuming, of course, that a canonical induction variable could be found.

Comment: Is there any other ways to get all the induction variables?

Comment: @user1701053 not that I know of, but you can take a look at the *indvars* pass ([desc](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#indvars),  [source](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/IndVarSimplify_8cpp_source.html)), which is concerned with identifying the induction variables in order to produce a single, canonical one.

Comment: @ZZB you should start accepting answers that worked for you. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)